# CakePHP 3 JWT-Auth gives 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: cakephp, jwt, cakephp-3.6

I'm using `CakePHP 3.6` and `JWT Auth` to enable token-based authentication in my application and frontend is written in `Angular 6`.

My login controller is like

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Http\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use Cake\Utility\Security;
use Crud\Controller\Component\CrudComponent;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'token']);
    }

    public function token()
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'expires_in' => 604800,
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    // 'exp' => time() + 604800
                ],
                    Security::getSalt())
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
    }
}
```

**AppController.php** contents

namespace App\Controller\Api;

```
<?php
use Cake\Controller\Controller;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete'
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                'Crud.Api',
                'Crud.ApiPagination'
            ]
        ]);

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ],
                    'finder' => 'auth'
                ],
                'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                    'parameter' => 'token',
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                    'finder' => 'auth',
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'id'
                    ],
                    'queryDatasource' => true
                ]
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize'
        ]);
    }

}
```

On sending request from the angular application to generate token works fine and following response is received.

[image]

But when using the token to send the request to other endpoints giving an error

```
401: Unauthorized access
```

[image]

The request/response header has token

[image]

What I tried?

- I tried with disabling **exp** while generating an access token.
- tried with disabling **debug** in CakePHP application.

**It is working great when CakePHP server application is run locally.**

Comment: Do some debugging in the authentication code to figure where exactly it bails out, that might give you a hint about the _why_.

Comment: @Anuj TBE: Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

in your .htaccess try this rule (if mod_rewrite is activated) :

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

With the Bitnami stack of LAMP (on EC2 AWS instance for example), the php-fdm module filter the header of every requests, and the "authorization" header is screwed up.

With this line, you can force to create a $_HTTP variable with the original Authorization header.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check in cakephp code if you are receiving the AUTHORIZATION in headers.

Comment: Also check in your htaccess if there is any redirection like http to https. Please remove these redirection.

Comment: $_SERVER check this on your cakephp action